# LyX - Highlight a result in table without using ERT

Tags: tables, lyx

I created a table in Lyx and I would like to put a square around a column to highlight the results without using the ERT command. Is that possible? I found that \colortbl and \mystrut can be useful but I don't see how to implement them. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Might we see the code for your table? It would be easier to help.

Comment: I'm using Beamer in Lyx and not Latex. If I export to Latex, the code is \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline 
\hline & {\small{}Mean} & {\small{}St. Dev.} & {\small{}Min} & {\small{}Max}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\hline &  &  &  & \\[-5ex]\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

Comment: I can help only on the code. I'll try to see how it can be done. You should post in your question a small compilable code. Which column would you like to highlight?

Comment: Sure, here it is. Wanted to highlight col C (i.e. put a red rectangle around it).

Comment: documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter

Comment: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 % this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 % (ERT) argument for the TOC
 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }


\usepackage{babel}

Comment: \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
\hline \hline
  A & B & C \\
  \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  
 \hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Comment: Code split to fit the # of words rule

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there rather than posting it in comments. When you've pasted it, highlight it and click the `{}` or use ctrl+k to format it as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with `pstricks`: I define a `node` at the top of the column, another node at the bottom, and I connect them with a `\ncbox` command. The width of the box is automatically calculated thanks to the `eqparbox` package: top node and bottom node use a system of tags which is used to compute the largest node. Note you have to use the `--enable-write18` switch for `pdflatex`, if the distribution is `MiKTeX`, `--shell-escape` if it is `TeX Live`. Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\newlength\boxsize

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} 
\hline \hline
 & {\small{}Mean} & \Rnode{T}{\eqmakebox[H]{\small{}St. Dev.}} & {\small{}Min} & {\small{}Max}\\
  \hline \hline \hline
  Blah & Blah & \Rnode{B}{\eqmakebox[H]{Blah}} & Blah & Blah \\[-5ex]
  \tabularnewline 
  \end{tabular}
\setlength{\boxsize}{\dimexpr\eqboxwidth{H}/2+\fboxsep\relax}
 \ncbox[linecolor=PaleVioletRed3, boxsize=\boxsize, nodesep=4pt]{T}{B}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic, many thanks! Any idea on how to use the -shell-escape in Lyx?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use it, and couldn't tell you, but  it should be in some configuration file, where pdflatex.exe is mentioned. Also, you don't need it if your engine is `xelatex`.

Comment: @FrancescaTonda see Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters. Read Help > Customization for more information on how to modify the underlying commands that LyX runs.